# ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK with android

Tags: android, ocr, abbyy

I'm trying to develop an android application using android studio which will recognize Arabic text from an image. I tried Tesseract OCR but unfortunately the result were inaccurate at all, so I wish to try ABBYY cloud OCR SDK. But i'm not able to find any useful tutorials or examples of how to use it with android. can someone recommend some tutorials/examples or guide me how to start using it?

Answer (score 2):

Detail of integration of Abbyy OCR sdk available on
[GitHub](https://github.com/abbyysdk)